# Unmet dependencies: emacs-snapshot : Depends: emacs-snapshot-common

Tags: software-installation

Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Emacs 27.1

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

But get error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-snapshot : Depends: emacs-snapshot-common (= 20221225:105176-48db8b68a8~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix the broken install ?, If not go for it first. Once resolved, 2. install any dependencies needed, then 3.install your actual package

Comment: Add the steps, you have tried to resolve the issue your are facing

Comment: @Aravinth This help: apt --fix-broken install

Comment: So there is no more ```You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.```, right ?

Comment: @Aravinth right

Comment: Then I hope, the actual issues also resolved ?